# Is my gedit-latex-plugin working properly?

Tags: 10.10, gedit, debug

I have installed gedit-latex-plugin(0.2 rc3) to be used with gedit(2.30.3) in ubuntu 10.04. If I use the command 
gedit file.tex& in terminal
the file is opened and it seems everything works fine but in the terminal, lots of comments appear, some of which are:

> ************************************************** 2012-03-31 22:14:27,263 DEBUG resources - Initializing resource locating
>
> 2012-03-31 22:14:27,361 DEBUG Preferences -  not found
>
> 2012-03-31 22:14:27,373 DEBUG JobManager - Created JobManager instance
>   147209196
>
> 2012-03-31 22:14:27,379 DEBUG GeditLaTeXPlugin - activate
>
> 2012-03-31 22:14:27,379 DEBUG WindowContext - init
>
> 2012-03-31 22:14:27,444 DEBUG GeditWindowDecorator -
>   _init_tab_decorators: initialized 0 decorators
>
> 2012-03-31 22:14:27,511 DEBUG GeditWindowDecorator -
>   active_tab_changed
>
> 2012-03-31 22:14:27,511 DEBUG GeditWindowDecorator - ----------
>   ADJUST: None
>
> 2012-03-31 22:14:27,513 DEBUG GeditWindowDecorator - No window-scope
>   views for this extension
>
> 2012-03-31 22:14:27,513 DEBUG GeditWindowDecorator -
>   _set_selected_bottom_view: 0
>
> 2012-03-31 22:14:27,514 DEBUG GeditWindowDecorator -
>   _set_selected_side_view: 0
>
> 2012-03-31 22:14:27,539 DEBUG GeditWindowDecorator - tab_added
>
> 2012-03-31 22:14:27,952 DEBUG GeditTabDecorator - loaded
>
> 2012-03-31 22:14:27,964 DEBUG GeditTabDecorator - _adjust_editor: URI
>   has changed
>
> 2012-03-31 22:14:27,965 DEBUG LaTeXCompletionHandler - init
>
> 2012-03-31 22:14:27,966 DEBUG LanguageModelFactory - Pickled object
>   found: /home/abcd/.gnome2/gedit/plugins/GeditLaTeXPlugin/latex.pkl
>
> 2012-03-31 22:14:28,075 DEBUG CompletionDistributor - init
>
> 2012-03-31 22:14:28,078 DEBUG WindowContext - Created view
>   LaTeXOutlineView
>
> 2012-03-31 22:14:28,078 DEBUG WindowContext - Created view IssueView
>
> 2012-03-31 22:14:28,079 DEBUG LaTeXEditor -
>   init(file:///home/abcd/dir1/file1.tex)
>
> 2012-03-31 22:14:28,079 DEBUG LaTeXEditor - Parsing document...
>
> 2012-03-31 22:14:28,080 DEBUG IssueView - init
>
> 2012-03-31 22:14:28,082 DEBUG IssueView - init finished
>
> 2012-03-31 22:14:28,092 INFO LaTeXEditor - LaTeXParser.parse: 0.010000
>
> 2012-03-31 22:14:28,092 DEBUG LaTeXEditor - Parsed 1599 bytes of
>   content
>
> 2012-03-31 22:14:28,093 DEBUG LaTeXOutlineView - set_outline
>
> 2012-03-31 22:14:28,093 DEBUG LaTeXOutlineView - init
>
> 2012-03-31 22:14:28,097 DEBUG LaTeXValidator - validate
>
> 2012-03-31 22:14:28,098 DEBUG LanguageModel - set_newcommands:
>
> 2012-03-31 22:14:28,102 DEBUG LaTeXEditor - Parsing finished
>
> 2012-03-31 22:14:28,105 DEBUG GeditWindowDecorator - ----------
>   ADJUST: .tex
>
> 2012-03-31 22:14:28,119 DEBUG GeditWindowDecorator -
>   _set_selected_bottom_view: 0
>
> 2012-03-31 22:14:28,120 DEBUG GeditWindowDecorator -
>   _set_selected_side_view: 0
>
> ---

I am not sure if the gedit-latex-plugin is working properly or is it facing some problem. Why are there so many debug messages? Can anybody please suggest what I should do?

Comment: Could you please look over [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) information on accepting answers if you don't know what "accepting an answer" means and why you should do it.

Answer (score 3):

Your gedit installation is working fine. Someone forgot to disable debug messages in the version of gedit you have (see [bug #584462](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit-latex-plugin/+bug/584462) ). Upgrading your gedit-latex-plugin to the version in Ubuntu 11.04 (located [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/gedit-latex-plugin)) will fix the problem, but you can invoke gedit in this way:

```
gedit file.tex 2> /dev/null &
```

as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that has been reported and fixed: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit-latex-plugin/+bug/584462

Have you tried downloading the actual plugin release version 0.2 rather than the release candidate?  Presumably the bug is fixed there.

In any case, the DEBUG messages do not indicate any problem.  Probably a developer simply forgot to disable them.